# A simple device to quickly erase the MBR on a sata drive

Tags: hard-drive

Is there a device that I can plug SATA disks into to erase the MBR?  I know this could be done with a computer, but I'd rather have something compact, not unlike a disk duplicator.  In fact I've even thought about using a disk duplicator to do this, but that would mean having to wait as long as it takes to duplicate the master disk, and since I can't find a 512-byte sata disk (edit, I haven't actually looked for one), that would be a lot of time wasted.

**Edit:**

The reason I'd like something is that I'm doing a LOT of these disks, and the reason I'm doing this is so that I can assemble the hardware, and have them PXE boot to install the operating system.  Some of these disks may be refurbished, so if there's a bootable disk installed, the BIOS may not automatically hit the PXE ROM.

Answer (score 2):

A simple USB/SATA connector and a one-liner on the command line appears to be a very quick, cheap and easy solution. You could even create some script that automatically erase the MBR if it detects a new disk on the USB/SATA bridge port.